# Will Dart work with ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, dart

I haven't been able to find any information concerning Dart and ASP.Net. I assume it will be compatible since you can run JavaScript with ASP.Net. Still, though, it would be good to make sure. Does anyone know the specifications for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart can be complied into Java Script , so for us , heavy weight .NET or Java developers with all our heavy ASP.NET and server side architecture machinery , I believe Dart will be a great finally easy to use 'java script' compiler -- for all the times you got messy , full of bugs , hard to test or decode .JS files.

In fact , it is long claimed that Google uses some in-house java script compiler to build Gmail and Google+ , so many guess they simply expose many of their already existing infra's to the world.

@Jeremy McGee , I think you are incorrect as Dart can be compiled to Java Script and run on any browser. 
What you are talking about is Dart virtual machine , which is currently supported only in new preview state Chromium web browser.
This virtual machine aims to work faster as it does not need to compile itself to java script.

ALSO , if you know about Google's vision to have a web browser OS , dart is their way of attracting developers to this web browser new OS , as it will be easy for developers to write new apps for it , also fits to their new HTML 5 / JS applications for current version of Google Chrome and Google Play for Android market .
Not far from now , you will be able to write Dart apps for Android .

Microsoft on the other hand are running towards HTML embedded for Windows 8 new run time engine which supports JS for writing new windows applications and perhaps even in the future XBOX applications.

AS both companies realized , there is a huge cave of 16-24 kids whom learned JS from some web tutorial , they give them all uniforms and send them to the battle.

Very interesting it is !!!

Answer (score 3):

If used as a client-side technology -- yes, Dart should work just fine.

However, as detailed [here](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/blog/2011/oct/11/google-dart-programming-prospects), Dart is intended for server-side as well as client-side use:

> Developers have not been able to create homogeneous systems that encompass both client and server, except for a few cases such as Node.js and Google Web Toolkit (GWT).

This, combined with its current lack of support in Microsoft browsers, may well limit its appeal to Microsoft developers.

Comment: I only use Mono ASP with C-Sharp, so there may be a problem there.

Answer (score 2):

Client side apps written with Dart can be converted to JavaScript (this is a key design feature of Dart, not just an add-on). When the client side app is running, it can access data from any webserver technology by using XmlHttpRequest (for example, a RESTful web server that responds to GET and POST).

In this respect, it is similar to writing a pure JavaScript client side app, or a Flash app that uses the server to send and retrieve data (think Gmail, Google Plus etc...).   Ideally, you'd also store data in the browser so that your app can also work offline.

Using this model, whether the server side itself is written in .net, java, ruby, python or some other is up to the developer.

Answer (score 1):

It will work on the client side but won't work on the server side since it isn't supported by .NET. You will be able to use it on the client side even in browsers which don't support it directly because Google created Dart -> JavaScript compiler.